# PyQt5: app doesn't start - segmentation error (core dumped)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I recently came back to a python app I had let aside for a while.

I made some slight amendments and suddenly the app refused to start.
In eclipse it doesn't give any comment other than terminated
When launched from the terminal with no option the message is

> Segmentation error (core dumped)

When launched with a -m option the message is

> Error while finding module specification for 'main.py'
>   (AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute '**path**')

Here is the main

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
from view.MainWindow import MainWindow
import sys

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow=MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
    translator.load("translate/fr_FR.qm")
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can somebody give me some guidance in the way to debug that

Comment: can you debug it in IDE? seems that posted code is OK

Comment: I am far from mastering the debug in Eclipse

Comment: It returns terminated exit value 139

Comment: please correct the indentation of your code, in python it is important. Also I recommend you execute your code without the help of an IDE using the terminal or CMD.

Comment: It does'nt have indent pb just when pasting here

Comment: Would you type some error message run it from the cmd or from the terminal?

Comment: even commenting lines from mainWindow= ... to app.installTranslator... and putting a simple print('hello') gives the same

Comment: @eyllanesc I gave the message when run from terminal in the post

Comment: Then the problem is the installation of the package, explain how you have installed PyQt5, what version of python3 you have, what is your OS.

Comment: I installed pyqt5 with pip in a virtual env with python 3.6. I had no time today to go further but I think I found the origin of the pb. An import was erroneous (two chars had been erased without me realizing it) After correction the crash no longer arrive. The only problem is that there was not clue about where the crash was situated.